# React Native fetch for HTTP2 endpoint can not get body

Tags: react-native

I use React Native fetch to POST to endpoint which is AWS Lambda. By default it's HTTP/2. That works perfectly fine with curl:

```
% curl -X POST https://yyyyyy.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Test/stripe_payment -H "x-api-key: xxxxx"
% {"errorCode": "OK", "client_secret": "zzzz"}
```

But the same from react native:

```
    try {
      response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/stripe_payment`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'x-api-key': API_KEY,
        },
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    console.log('API response', response);
```

Returns only Lambda headers, not body:

```
API response {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "dce744f2-6755-47e0-9a9d-74921ae64eba", "offset": 0, "size": 100}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "dce744f2-6755-47e0-9a9d-74921ae64eba", "offset": 0, "size": 100}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"content-length": "100", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Fri, 11 Nov 2022 19:33:22 GMT", "x-amz-apigw-id": "bc58SFhsFiAFp1A=", "x-amzn-requestid": "fc157dbb-72d2-459e-a391-1ece0ff9680f", "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-636ea381-0c40c8ec31bb9c4f52d0e44b;Sampled=0"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "https://yyyyyy.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Test/stripe_payment"}
```

Above response is correct, but it contains only headers, no body.
I do suspect that is because of HTTP/2 binary protocol, looking at some discussions looks like react native did not support it correctly in the past.

Any hints ?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

ok, looks like i have found the answer: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24520